# Word2Vec Giving Characters instead of Words

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, gensim

I have tokenized my strings and made a Pandas column out of them and if I print the column `df['word_splits']` it looks like this.

```
0    ['explanation', 'why', 'the', 'edits', 'made',...
1    ["d'aww", '!', 'he', 'matches', 'this', 'backg...
2    ['hey', 'man', ',', "i'm", 'really', 'not', 't...
3    ['more', 'i', "can't", 'make', 'any', 'real', ...
4    ['you', ',', 'sir', ',', 'are', 'my', 'hero', ...
Name: word_splits, dtype: object
```

Next, I'm running Word2Vec

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=df["word_splits"])
```

When I print out the vocabulary, using

```
words = list(model.wv.vocab)
print(words)
```

I'm getting characters instead of a long list of words (vocabulary).

```
['[', "'", 'e', 'x', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'n', 't', 'i', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'h', 'y', 'd', 's', 'm', 'u', 'r', 'c', 'f', 'v', '?', '"', 'j', 'g', 'k', '.', ']', '!', 'b', '-', 'q', 'z']
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**Potential Issue:**
The sentences should be a list of lists.

**Potential Solution:**

```py
#Invoke library
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

#Change the sentences into a list of lists.
s = [['explanation', 'why', 'the', 'edits', 'made'], ['hey', 'man', ',', "i'm", 'really', 'not']]

#Build model
model = Word2Vec(s, size=10, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)

#Inspect the vocabulary
list(model.wv.vocab)

#['made', 'explanation', 'hey', ',', 'why', 'edits', 'not', "i'm", 'man', 'the', 'really']
```